# Transistor - Control current flow

Tags: power-supply, transistors, current-limiting

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXdqwO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am having trouble finding how to limit the current flow from the collector to the emitter of a transistor. (Is it possible? I know it is possible to amplify the current but I don't know if I can reduce it.) I am trying to avoid PWM and I want to maintain a steady voltage output. This is going to be used for a current limiting circuit in a variable power supply I am designing.

Comment: Try showing your circuit.

Comment: Yes it's possible. The right way to do it depends on a lot of context you haven't told us. If you are "trying to avoid PWM" part of that context is the power you expect to dissipate in the transistor, so voltage, current, what the load is, why you want to avoid PWM are part of the context.

Comment: @calthecoder: Use the schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Google "emitter follower" and see if that helps you. A simple schematic would really help. Also, does your system have a microcontroller with ADC and DAC available or are you trying for something based on discrete components only?

Comment: If your objective is a fixed and stable current, there's a name for that: a current sink (or source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you limit the base current, then the collector current will be limited to \$\beta\$*Ibase. Do remember however that \$\beta\$ is not constant, varying with collector current, temperature, and probably collector voltage as well.

Alternatively, if you pass the emitter current through a small resistor, and servo that using an opamp to control the base voltage, then you will have much tighter control of the collector current.

You choose.